# (VB6 - Access) Populate TextBox on conditions of multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I can enter the data in database by normal VB6 method (I am going to explain in one line code)

```
.Fields("PhoneName") = PhoneName.Text
```

but i want to add or edit the data from database like

```
ComboBox1   ComboBox2   Combobox3   TextBox
```

where table contains

```
 Name,  ID,   Column1,  Column2,  Column3.

  A      X      1        2       3
  B      Y      2        3       1
  C      Z      3        1       2
```

now i want ComboBox1 Contains data from Column [name]
Combobox2 contains data from column [ID]
now Combobox3 should contain all the remaining columns (not data)

so when i will choose the values for ComboBoxes then textbox will filled with specific value from table...

Please tell me atleast logic....

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Row Source of the combo box.
Access has a Row Source editor that can help you assign the rows as needed.
Make sure that the combobox Column Count property matches though the wizard should help you.

You will have to construct a filter since these comboboxes will pull data from the database but are not necessarily linked to a column.